# Are there any good tutorials on SHARC-Gaussian interface?

Tags: software, gaussian, reference-request, potential-energy-surface

I am an aspiring quantum chemist planning on trying out the SHARC approach to study excited state proton transfer dynamics of organic molecules. I am comfortable with Gaussian 16 as that is the software where we do most of out work. I want to utilize the SHARC - Gaussian interface to use SHARC along with the TDDFT functionality of Gaussian. The tutorial given along with the manual only covers the MOLCAS/OpenMolcas interface.

Please let me know if you know any good resources to learn the SHARC Gaussian interface from.

Comment: Since almost a month has passed since you asked this, I wonder if you have any update now?

Comment: No, there has been no updates.